# duplicate data in firebase real time database( javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```js
var a = prompt("What is your phone number");
var database = firebase.database();
var fruits = database.ref('fruits');
var data = {
  name: (a),
  count: (a)
}
database.ref('fruits').push(data);
fruits.push(data, finished);
function finished(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('ooops');
  } else {
    console.log('data saved!');
  }
}
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (error) {
   console.log("Error: " + error.code);
});
var playersRef = firebase.database().ref("fruits");
playersRef.orderByChild("name").on("child_added", function(data) {
   var PD = (data.val().name);
   confirm(PD)
});
```

For some reason, this code is producing a duplicate of itself in the firebase real-time database. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two consecutive lines of code that each push the same data, resulting in your duplicate.

`database.ref('fruits').push(data);
fruits.push(data, finished);`

Try deleting one of those lines

Comment: Great! Glad to help.